# Why does _init cause a fault within __libc_init_array on an STM32F4?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, gcc

I'm trying to build a firmware for an STM32F401CCU6 "black pill" development board using a CMake toolchain I've created from scratch in order to test [mapping C++ classes to peripheral memory addresses](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uwzuAGtAEFk). After setting up the interrupt vector table in C++ and creating a custom reset handler, I see that the compiler automatically includes a C runtime initializer called `_mainCRTStartup`. I was able to get C++ object static initialization working (and an LED turned on) by re-implementing `__libc_init_array` in C++ which is called before the MCU hits `main()` but I do not want to try and side-step the C runtime included with GCC.

I attempted to move the reset handler vector to _mainCRTStartup but I get a crash (interrupts to default handler loop) within a call to `atexit` which I overwrote since it was a weakly linked symbol. Next, it would crash at `__libc_init_array` when it calls `_init`.

Here is the compiler's output for `_init`:

```
Disassembly of section .init:

08001b70 <_init>:
 8001b70:   b5f8        push    {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
 8001b72:   bf00        nop
 8001b74:   bcf8        pop {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7}
 8001b76:   bc08        pop {r3}
 8001b78:   469e        mov lr, r3
 8001b7a:   4770        bx  lr
```

Here is the compiler's output for `__libc_init_array`:

```
08001368 <__libc_init_array>:
 8001368:   b570        push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
 800136a:   4e0d        ldr r6, [pc, #52]   ; (80013a0 <__libc_init_array+0x38>)
 800136c:   4d0d        ldr r5, [pc, #52]   ; (80013a4 <__libc_init_array+0x3c>)
 800136e:   1b76        subs    r6, r6, r5
 8001370:   10b6        asrs    r6, r6, #2
 8001372:   d006        beq.n   8001382 <__libc_init_array+0x1a>
 8001374:   2400        movs    r4, #0
 8001376:   3401        adds    r4, #1
 8001378:   f855 3b04   ldr.w   r3, [r5], #4
 800137c:   4798        blx r3
 800137e:   42a6        cmp r6, r4
 8001380:   d1f9        bne.n   8001376 <__libc_init_array+0xe>
 8001382:   4e09        ldr r6, [pc, #36]   ; (80013a8 <__libc_init_array+0x40>)
 8001384:   4d09        ldr r5, [pc, #36]   ; (80013ac <__libc_init_array+0x44>)
 8001386:   1b76        subs    r6, r6, r5
 8001388:   f000 fbf2   bl  8001b70 <_init>
 800138c:   10b6        asrs    r6, r6, #2
 800138e:   d006        beq.n   800139e <__libc_init_array+0x36>
 8001390:   2400        movs    r4, #0
 8001392:   3401        adds    r4, #1
 8001394:   f855 3b04   ldr.w   r3, [r5], #4
 8001398:   4798        blx r3
 800139a:   42a6        cmp r6, r4
 800139c:   d1f9        bne.n   8001392 <__libc_init_array+0x2a>
 800139e:   bd70        pop {r4, r5, r6, pc}
 80013a0:   08001c30    stmdaeq r0, {r4, r5, sl, fp, ip}
 80013a4:   08001c30    stmdaeq r0, {r4, r5, sl, fp, ip}
 80013a8:   08001c38    stmdaeq r0, {r3, r4, r5, sl, fp, ip}
 80013ac:   08001c30    stmdaeq r0, {r4, r5, sl, fp, ip}
```

I can see that `_init` appears to put an invalid address into the link register before it attempts to branch back but this causes a fault. Is there some compiler setting I'm missing which is causing this behavior? My CMake compiler options (spread out between CMakeLists.txt and toolchain file) are the following:

```
# Set target operating system
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

# Find compilers
find_program(CMAKE_C_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-gcc
    PATHS C:/msys64/mingw64/bin
    REQUIRED
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
find_program(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-g++
    PATHS C:/msys64/mingw64/bin
    REQUIRED
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
find_program(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-gcc
    PATHS C:/msys64/mingw64/bin
    REQUIRED
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH)

# Always compile statically
set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY)

# Set compiler flags
add_compile_options(
    -mthumb
    -mcpu=cortex-m4
    -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
    -mfloat-abi=hard
)

# Set linker flags
add_link_options(
    -mthumb
    -mcpu=cortex-m4
    -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
    -mfloat-abi=hard
)

# Project link options
target_link_options(${elf_file} PRIVATE
    LINKER:-Map=${map_file}
    LINKER:--cref
    -T ${linker_script}
    -fno-exceptions
    --specs=nosys.specs
    --specs=nano.specs
)
```

Comment: Most CRT support both C and C++ nowadays. Depends on what you mean with "C++", if you wish for the latest C++2x with it's very complicated rules for static initialization, well... it might not be supported. The C++98/C++03 ways of doing things should be though, in which case the main difference is that the CRT calls constructors during start-up when in C++ mode.

Comment: I'm currently not having any issues with static initialization or C++, I'm just wondering how to get the default C runtime to work without causing a hard fault in `_init`. This question has almost nothing to do with C++ itself.

Comment: Ok well, anyway you might want to look into the linker scrip and map file instead of the make file, to see where things are supposed to be stored and where they actually ended up. Also it's a good idea to always compile embedded systems. with `-ffreestanding`.

Comment: Oh and also always check where your stack pointer is at when the crash happens.

Comment: Do you use some stock GCC or from some vendor? You might want to check and compile it with ST CubeIDE to see what might be wrong.

Comment: @Justme I am using the `mingw-w64-x86_64-arm-none-eabi-gcc` package from MSYS2 which includes GCC version 10.1.0-2 and newlib version 3.3.0-1.

Comment: Hmm I've used the [Arm GNU Toolchain](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/downloads) with C++17 - I faintly remember, that I had to tackle some issues in the linker file to make it work with a complete startup written in C++.

Comment: Tip: linker script.;